# Plesk login page will not load

Tags: mysql, plesk

I am hoping someone can help me.

I am seeing the following issue when trying to access the plesk control panel:

> ERROR: Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Additionally, an exception has occurred while trying to report this error:

> Zend_Exception 
> No entry is registered for key 'translate' (Abstract.php:144)

Search for related Knowledge Base articles

> ERROR: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129 Stack trace: #0 /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=ps...', 'admin', '', Array) #1 /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #2 /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #3 /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('select param, v...', Array) #4 /opt/psa/admin/plib/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(30): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('select param, v...', Array) #5 /opt/psa/admin/plib/db.php(36): Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('select param, v...') #6 /opt/psa/admin/plib/db.php(212): db_query('select param, v...', false) #7 /opt/psa/admin/plib/Plesk/Mode.php(439): get_param('disable_provisi... (Abstract.php:144)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point here is that Plesk is trying to access MySQL without using a password.
This means that the password is somehow missing or not recognized.
Try to reset it:

```
# plesk bin admin -p -passwd 'newpleskadminpassword'
```

If the issue still persists after that, re-generate Plesk encryption keys:

```
# /opt/psa/admin/sbin/encrypt_keygen
```